# how to make a success messages in a script?

Tags: php, mysql

**I'm trying to send a success message through a variable but it doesn't work.**

```
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO category SET
            name='$name'";


 if ($sql)
{
$success = '';
}
    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted category.';
        include INC_DIR.'error.inc.php';
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Philip G, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass messages as a parameter through `header()` like,

```
header('Location: page.php?msg=success');
```

and in *page.php* you can accept the message like

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))   // if a parameter msg is present in url
{
  $msg=$_GET['msg'];      // accept the value from url
  if($msg=='success')    // if the parameter value is success
  {
    echo "Your message";    // echo your message
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use sessions to store the actual message. Just redirect to the current page and unset that session variable it after it's displayed so that refreshing won't show the same message again. If that's what you want, of course.